# Edit multiple files in ubuntu

Tags: file, editing

I have multiple(more than 100) `.c` files and I want to change a particular text from all the file in which that text exists. I am using ubuntu!

How can I do it?(I will prefer command line rather than installing any application)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
OLD=searchtext
NEW=replacedtext
YOURFILE=/path/to/your/file
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" $YOURFILE > $TMPFILE && mv $TMPFILE $YOURFILE
rm -rf $TMPFILE
```

you can also use `find` to find your files:

```
find /path/to/parent/dir -name "*.c" -exec sed 's/$OLD/$NEW/g' {} > $TMPFILE && mv $TMPFILE {} \;
```

`find /path/to/parent/dir -name "*.c"` finds all files with name `*.c` under `/path/to/parent/dir`. `-exec command {} \;` executes the `command` in the found file. `{}` stands for the found file.

Comment: Still this works only for one file! I want to do it for all the files in my directory!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), which lets your replace some text with other text (among other things)

example

```
sed s/day/night/ oldfile newfile
```

will change all occurences of "day" with "night" in the oldfile, and store the new, changed version in the newfile

to run on many files, there are a few things you could do:

- use [foreach](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) in your favorite shell
- use find like this
  `find . -name "namepattern" -exec sed -i "sed-expr" "{}" \;`
- use file patterns like this: sed -i "sed-expr" *pattern?.cpp

where *pattern?.cpp is just a name pattern for all files that starts with some string, then has "pattern" in them, and has any letter and a ".cpp" suffix

Comment: But I want to do the same thing for multiple files!